# How to Append to an Array in BigQuery or: How I Learned to Handle Optional Responses in Multiple Choice Typeform Payload

Tags: json, google-bigquery, typeform

#### Working with Typeform Surveys

Here is the survey design for question 1:
[image: survey question 1]

Here is the survey design for question 2:
[image: survey question 2]

Here is the survey design for question 3:
[image: survey question 3]

#### Response Data

I took the survey twice.

On the first submission:

1. (favorite color) red, blue, Other: yellow
2. (quest) To seek the holy grail
3. (another question) what is your name

On the second submission:

1. (favorite color) red, Other: orange
2. (quest) Other: something else
3. (another question) What... is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?

Here is a sample JSON file, which I saved as option.json:

```json
{   "event_id": "EVENT_ID_1",   "event_type": "form_response",   "form_response": {     "submitted_at": "2022-07-12T22:51:01Z",     "token": "TOKEN_1",     "calculated": null,     "answers": [{       "value": {         "boolean": null,         "file_url": null,         "url": null,         "phone_number": null,         "email": null,         "field": {           "ref": "QUESTION_REF_1",           "id": "QUESTION_ID_1",           "type": "multiple_choice"         },         "text": null,         "number": null,         "choices": {           "labels": [{             "value": "red"           }, {             "value": "blue"           }],           "other": "yellow"         },         "type": "choices",         "date": null,         "choice": null       }     }, {       "value": {         "boolean": null,         "file_url": null,         "url": null,         "phone_number": null,         "email": null,         "field": {           "ref": "QUESTION_REF_2",           "id": "QUESTION_ID_2",           "type": "multiple_choice"         },         "text": null,         "number": null,         "choices": {           "labels": [{             "value": "To seek the holy grail"           }],           "other": null         },         "type": "choices",         "date": null,         "choice": null       }     }, {       "value": {         "boolean": null,         "file_url": null,         "url": null,         "phone_number": null,         "email": null,         "field": {           "ref": "QUESTION_REF_3",           "id": "QUESTION_ID_3",           "type": "short_text"         },         "text": "what is your name",         "number": null,         "choices": null,         "type": "text",         "date": null,         "choice": null       }     }],     "form_id": "FORM_ID",     "variables": [],     "definition": {       "id": "FORM_ID",       "title": "Test Multiple Choice Other",       "fields": [{         "value": {           "ref": "QUESTION_REF_1",           "id": "QUESTION_ID_1",           "type": "multiple_choice",           "title": "What is your favorite color?",           "choices": [{             "value": {               "id": "CHOICE_ID_1",               "label": "red"             }           }, {             "value": {               "id": "CHOICE_ID_2",               "label": "blue"             }           }],           "allow_multiple_selections": "true",           "allow_other_choice": "true"         }       }, {         "value": {           "ref": "QUESTION_REF_2",           "id": "QUESTION_ID_2",           "type": "multiple_choice",           "title": "What is your quest?",           "choices": [{             "value": {               "id": "CHOICE_ID_3",               "label": "To seek the holy grail"             }           }],           "allow_multiple_selections": "true",           "allow_other_choice": "true"         }       }, {         "value": {           "ref": "QUESTION_REF_3",           "id": "QUESTION_ID_3",           "type": "short_text",           "title": "What else could I ask?",           "choices": [],           "allow_multiple_selections": null,           "allow_other_choice": null         }       }]     },     "hidden": null,     "landed_at": "2022-07-12T22:49:34Z"   },   "_sdc_received_at": "2022-07-12T22:51:33.248Z",   "_sdc_sequence": "1657666262148",   "_sdc_batched_at": "2022-07-12T22:57:17.785Z",   "_sdc_table_version": "0" }
{   "event_id": "EVENT_ID_2",   "event_type": "form_response",   "form_response": {     "submitted_at": "2022-07-12T22:53:08Z",     "token": "TOKEN_2",     "calculated": null,     "answers": [{       "value": {         "boolean": null,         "file_url": null,         "url": null,         "phone_number": null,         "email": null,         "field": {           "ref": "QUESTION_REF_1",           "id": "QUESTION_ID_1",           "type": "multiple_choice"         },         "text": null,         "number": null,         "choices": {           "labels": [{             "value": "red"           }],           "other": "orange"         },         "type": "choices",         "date": null,         "choice": null       }     }, {       "value": {         "boolean": null,         "file_url": null,         "url": null,         "phone_number": null,         "email": null,         "field": {           "ref": "QUESTION_REF_2",           "id": "QUESTION_ID_2",           "type": "multiple_choice"         },         "text": null,         "number": null,         "choices": {           "labels": [],           "other": "something else"         },         "type": "choices",         "date": null,         "choice": null       }     }, {       "value": {         "boolean": null,         "file_url": null,         "url": null,         "phone_number": null,         "email": null,         "field": {           "ref": "QUESTION_REF_3",           "id": "QUESTION_ID_3",           "type": "short_text"         },         "text": "What... is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?",         "number": null,         "choices": null,         "type": "text",         "date": null,         "choice": null       }     }],     "form_id": "FORM_ID",     "variables": [],     "definition": {       "id": "FORM_ID",       "title": "Test Multiple Choice Other",       "fields": [{         "value": {           "ref": "QUESTION_REF_1",           "id": "QUESTION_ID_1",           "type": "multiple_choice",           "title": "What is your favorite color?",           "choices": [{             "value": {               "id": "CHOICE_ID_1",               "label": "red"             }           }, {             "value": {               "id": "CHOICE_ID_2",               "label": "blue"             }           }],           "allow_multiple_selections": "true",           "allow_other_choice": "true"         }       }, {         "value": {           "ref": "QUESTION_REF_2",           "id": "QUESTION_ID_2",           "type": "multiple_choice",           "title": "What is your quest?",           "choices": [{             "value": {               "id": "CHOICE_ID_3",               "label": "To seek the holy grail"             }           }],           "allow_multiple_selections": "true",           "allow_other_choice": "true"         }       }, {         "value": {           "ref": "QUESTION_REF_3",           "id": "QUESTION_ID_3",           "type": "short_text",           "title": "What else could I ask?",           "choices": [],           "allow_multiple_selections": null,           "allow_other_choice": null         }       }]     },     "hidden": null,     "landed_at": "2022-07-12T22:51:27Z"   },   "_sdc_received_at": "2022-07-12T22:53:38.604Z",   "_sdc_sequence": "1657666388772",   "_sdc_batched_at": "2022-07-12T22:57:17.818Z",   "_sdc_table_version": "0" }
```

#### Then I created a table in BigQuery using that option.json file:

[image: BQ Create Table with Console]

I am trying to flatten this in a way that I can easily share it with others.

1. sequence for multiple choice responses: one issue is that I need to keep track of how many options someone selects for each multiple choice question.
2. another problem is that I need to be able to handle the "other" option, which does not get saved in the same way as a regular multiple choice option.

What I have so far works fine as long as no one selects "optional" in the multiple choice types:

```sql
SELECT
  tf.event_id,
  a.value.field.id AS question_id,
  f.value.title AS question_title,
  a.value.type AS question_type,
  CASE
    WHEN a.value.type = 'choices' THEN c.value
    WHEN a.value.type = 'text' THEN a.value.text
  END AS value,
  IF( a.value.type = 'choices' , choices_index+1 , 1 ) AS sequence,
  COALESCE( ARRAY_LENGTH( a.value.choices.labels ) , 1 ) AS sequence_end,
FROM `<PROJECT_ID>.<DATASET_ID>.option` AS tf
LEFT JOIN UNNEST( tf.form_response.answers ) AS a
LEFT JOIN UNNEST( a.value.choices.labels ) AS c WITH OFFSET AS choices_index
INNER JOIN UNNEST( form_response.definition.fields ) f
  ON a.value.field.id = f.value.id
```

Result:
[image: query result]

Result in JSON:

```json
[{
  "event_id": "EVENT_ID_1",
  "question_id": "QUESTION_ID_1",
  "question_title": "What is your favorite color?",
  "question_type": "choices",
  "value": "red",
  "sequence": "1",
  "sequence_end": "2"
}, {
  "event_id": "EVENT_ID_1",
  "question_id": "QUESTION_ID_1",
  "question_title": "What is your favorite color?",
  "question_type": "choices",
  "value": "blue",
  "sequence": "2",
  "sequence_end": "2"
}, {
  "event_id": "EVENT_ID_1",
  "question_id": "QUESTION_ID_2",
  "question_title": "What is your quest?",
  "question_type": "choices",
  "value": "To seek the holy grail",
  "sequence": "1",
  "sequence_end": "1"
}, {
  "event_id": "EVENT_ID_1",
  "question_id": "QUESTION_ID_3",
  "question_title": "What else could I ask?",
  "question_type": "text",
  "value": "what is your name",
  "sequence": "1",
  "sequence_end": "1"
}, {
  "event_id": "EVENT_ID_2",
  "question_id": "QUESTION_ID_1",
  "question_title": "What is your favorite color?",
  "question_type": "choices",
  "value": "red",
  "sequence": "1",
  "sequence_end": "1"
}, {
  "event_id": "EVENT_ID_2",
  "question_id": "QUESTION_ID_2",
  "question_title": "What is your quest?",
  "question_type": "choices",
  "value": null,
  "sequence": null,
  "sequence_end": "0"
}, {
  "event_id": "EVENT_ID_2",
  "question_id": "QUESTION_ID_3",
  "question_title": "What else could I ask?",
  "question_type": "text",
  "value": "What... is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?",
  "sequence": "1",
  "sequence_end": "1"
}]
```

I want the result to append the "optional" responses to the end of the list of the multiple-choice selections, which would mean my total query result should have 9 rows.

Specifically:
EVENT_ID_1, QUESTION_ID_1 should have 3 rows:

1. red (sequence: 1, sequence_end: 3)
2. blue (sequence: 2, sequence_end: 3)
3. yellow (sequence: 3, sequence_end: 3)

and
EVENT_ID_2, QUESTION_ID_1 should have 2 rows:

1. red (sequence: 1, sequence_end: 2)
2. orange (sequence: 2, sequence_end: 2)

and
EVENT_ID_3, QUESTION_ID_2 should have 1 non-null row:

1. something else (sequence: 1, sequence_end: 1)

I need your brilliance. Could you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic SQL approach can be:

- Find all the normal response values.
- Find all the other response values.
- Combine them together using [union all](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#set_operators)

Below is an example from your shared data:

```sql
with titles as (
select distinct f.value.id question_id,f.value.title as question_title 
from `TABLE_NAME` tf
,UNNEST( form_response.definition.fields ) f
)
,response as(
 
select tf.event_id 
,a.value.field.id as question_id
,a.value.type AS question_type
,CASE
    WHEN a.value.type = 'choices' THEN c.value
    WHEN a.value.type = 'text' THEN a.value.text
  END AS value
from `TABLE_NAME` tf
,UNNEST( tf.form_response.answers ) AS a
left join UNNEST( a.value.choices.labels ) AS c
 
)
,optionals as(
  select distinct tf.event_id 
    ,a.value.field.id as question_id
    ,a.value.type AS question_type
    ,a.value.choices.other value
  from `TABLE_NAME` tf
  ,UNNEST( tf.form_response.answers ) AS a
  where a.value.choices.other is not null
 
)
select t.question_title
,f.*
,row_number() over (partition by event_id,f.question_id,question_type ) sequence
,count(*) over (partition by event_id,f.question_id,question_type) sequence_end
from (
select * from response where value is not null
union all
select * from optionals
)f
left join titles t on f.question_id = t.question_id
order by event_id,question_id
```

Above is just an example, your query also works fine all you have to do is get another result set which will contain only **optional** value and merge both results together.

N.B Use [Temp tables instead of CTE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute#avoid_multiple_evaluations_of_the_same_common_table_expressions_ctes).